# Network icon incorrectly indicates that there is no connection upon awaking from hibernate (Win10/7)

Tags: networking, hibernate

I have seen the opposite of my question in this forum but did not find an answer to my question.

I have a Win10 tower (HDD not SSD) and when I hibernate and awake the machine the network icon indicates I have no connection.  Except I do.  If I run troubleshoot it still thinks that there is no connection.  I am using Ethernet (no WLAN) and I had this same issue under WIN7.  Has anyone else experienced this issue and if so what is the fix?

Thanks.

Comment: Does it indicate that you have no internet connection (yellow exclamation over network icon) or no ethernet connection (red X on icon)? Does it ever recover on it's own?

Comment: Similar question here http://superuser.com/q/691107/285900

Answer (score 0):

You can [try this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/no-internet-connection-after-hibernate-or-sleep/aec205c0-e791-400d-9b9d-f228f20167f2):

> In Device Manager right click on your network adapter and select
>   Properties then Power Management and uncheck the box to Allow to turn
>   off to save power.

Comment: Thank you Vojtech, I will try that -- I also did something else that appears to work as I have not experienced this issue since I closed any app that would ping the network (Outlook) or get a "push" update (newspaper site).  I did leave open browser pages that were static. Since then I have not had this issue but I have unchecked the box you recommended and will see if that solves the issue if I keep Outlook and my default news site open when I hibernate.