# Why does sleeping kill my internet and how can I fix it?

Tags: networking, windows-10, sleep

So new problem for me on Win10 on a desktop attached to ethernet:

When I put the computer to sleep (basically at this point just shutting the monitors off) no matter how short the time, I lose my wired internet connection.

Before sleeping: (notice the connected computer icon)

[image: has interwebs]

After sleeping:

[image: no interwebs!]

Looked here: [How not to lose Wifi after going to Standby mode?](https://superuser.com/questions/652276/how-not-to-lose-wifi-after-going-to-standby-mode) and looked at the linked MS forum but wasn't a big help.
Have checked off all the power-saver settings that are general to Win10 but when I go ctrl-panel -> device manager -> adapter I don't have a 'power-management' option.

See:

[image: no power management]

So I'm not sure where/what to try next.

Comment: do you use Virtualbox? this is known to cause it for several years.