# Why can I only access internet after sleep mode or hibernate?

Tags: windows-7, internet-connection, lenovo-laptop

I have Windows 7, Lenovo Z50.

For a while I went from dynamic IP to a static one. I realized that it wasn't for me, so I went back to dynamic IP (I think I did it right when I went back to dynamic).

I don't know if my problem is related to this changes.

Now I can't have access to internet connection when I start my laptop (the wireless icon has red cross). I have to go to hibernate mode or sleep mode to get access to the internet. I have to do this every time start my laptop.

I tried every solution in the book:

1. I went to my BIOS and found my wireless connection already enabled.
2. I checked IPv4/TCP and IPv6/TCP
3. When I start my laptop I went to Windows Mobility Center but couldn't click on activate wireless connection.
4. I deleted the config file in regedit.
5. I upgraded my driver

Nothing seems to work. **How can I gain my internet access without needing to hibernate or sleep mode?**

Comment: Hello, the moment it happened, have you tried to do any of the following: forget the network, then tried to reconnect, flush dns, ipconfig release & renew, reset winsock. I experienced this on my laptop before for random of times, what I did was to just ipconfig /renew.

Comment: thanks i will try those, but can you just go one by one in detail

Comment: Hello I tried ipconfig /release and /renew, it says that no operation can be done if the media is disconnected

Comment: Hi, I forgot to mention that it will show that since you're on wifi and not on ethernet. Nevertheless, I searched a quite similar issue here on superuser forum, this might help you out, https://superuser.com/questions/652276/how-not-to-lose-wifi-after-going-to-standby-mode